# Django ORM filter SUM different related objects

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Skill(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Experience(models.Model):
    date_from = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_to = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, related_name='experience', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SkillExperience(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='skill_experience')
    experience = models.ForeignKey(Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='skill_experience')
    years_experience = models.IntegerField()
```

I need a query to retrieve Developers that have at years_experience of at least 5 in skill code 'python', for example. However I can't simply do `Developer.objects.filter(skill_experience__years_experience__gte=5)` because I could have two experiences in Python but one 3 years and another one 2 years and that won't show in the query above. So I need to sum up all the years_experience that are from skill__code="Python" and evaluate it. Is there some way to do it with a single query?

Comment: I assume it is `skill__code='Python'` instead of `skill__name=...`?

Comment: Yes, exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to sum up the `years_experience` and then filter on the `total_years`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Developer.objects.filter(
    # filter on Python skills (so exclude for example Java)
    experience__skill_experience__skill__code='Python'
).annotate(
    # sum up these years
    total_years=Sum('experience__skill_experience__years_experience')
).filter(
    # check if the total is at least five
    total_years__gte=5
)
```

Comment: That looks good, however I think you meant `experience__skill_experience` since it's experience that's linked to Developer and not SkillExperience.

Comment: @Luc: yes. Indeed, well spotted :)

Comment: I know I already accpted your answer. but how to proceed if I'm on a loop of skills and I need to check an OR, so let's say looping this array: [{code: 'python', years_experience: 5}, {code: 'node', years_experience: 2}] and I need to return Devs who have either 5 years xp with python OR 2 years xp with node? You have any idea?

Comment: @Luc: can you ask a new question?

Comment: There you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312167/django-orm-filter-sum-different-related-objects-on-a-loop